# Python 3.5.2 download vimeo video

Tags: python-3.x

When I use view-source in a html browser it brings up the source code.

```
view-source:https://vimeo.com.video/(video id #)
```

This brings up the source code of the underlying video so I can choose what quality video I want to download.

I want to do the same thing automatically instead of having to go through the browser all the time to download a vimeo video.

When I try to do the same thing using python 3.5.2 I end up getting

```
No connection adapters were found for 'view-source:https://player.vimeo.com/video/(video id #)
```

In the browser, when I try to bring up the page as a regular page all I get is the error page Sorry, this is a private video and cannot be displayed. I don't get the error code on the same video when I use view-source in the browser instead I get the source code and choose which quality I want.

In Python I get the No connection adapters when I try to use view-source. If I don't then all I get is Error 403: Forbidden.

I have tried both with urllib.requests and BeautifulSoup and cannot get anywhere with either option.

```
page = requests.get('https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + video[0])
html2 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

Above gives the Sorry page.

```
html1 = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + video[0]
print(html1)
result = requests.get(html1, headers=headers)
with urllib.request.urlopen(html1) as att:
    html2 = att.read()
```

Above gives Error 403: Forbidden

How do I get it so I can get the 'view-source' source code from the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

For private video(embed only), it's going to give a 403 status code.

```py
>>> # Not an embed only video
>>> requests.get('https://player.vimeo.com/video/492406...') 
<Response [200]>
```

This worked for me.

You could use this small lightweight package to easily download any Vimeo videos and retrieve metadata
https://pypi.org/project/vimeo-downloader/